# Is there any API or Scraping methods to get Facebook users' phone numbers?

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

My goal is to get the users' phone numbers by their UID or custom links even though they are not my friends. Tino Group Assistant is doing this really well, how can I get users' phone number like this extension? Any API or method, extensions is suggested? Link of the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tino-group-assistant/pabbijpgioknanfnfidhocohgicpcpnl?hl=vi&fbclid=IwAR0HpFWjSMQDgLYA9LlLW_eWLQN2Q9zcBVF-bMb8rjQMlk9fZul9fZkyLWA

Input: List of Facebook users' ID or links

Expected output: List of users' phone numbers based on UID or links.

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, and there is no api for getting the phone number. also, any user data is none of your business unless the user specifically authorized you to use it.

Comment: this UID is collected from users, they send us and allow us to collect their phone number...

Comment: they have to do this with the api, by authorizing your app. else, everyone could just use any user id. and if they provide the UID, why would they not just provide their phone number too? sounds over-complicated.

Comment: This is for an action requiring users to submit a form, we do require users to provide the phone number, however, we also expect that it's not the fake ones.

Comment: users could also just enter a fake user id...

Answer (score 0):

No. See here for more information, from the Facebook API.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/

Comment: but the Tino still can get that info. How can that do? Check this:https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tino-group-assistant/pabbijpgioknanfnfidhocohgicpcpnl?hl=vi&fbclid=IwAR0HpFWjSMQDgLYA9LlLW_eWLQN2Q9zcBVF-bMb8rjQMlk9fZul9fZkyLWA

Comment: Probably scraping Facebook which is not allowed by Facebook Terms of Service or Platform Policy.

Comment: Please show me the details...

Comment: I work at Facebook. Why would I show you details on how to do something we don't allow?